# Returns 404 after login Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, handler

I'm trying to use the 404 page method in Laravel, it's working fine, the problem is that page 404 is always returned after login, I could not understand why.

**My Handler for 404 page**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
      if($this->isHttpException($exception))
         {
             switch ($exception->getStatusCode())
                 {
                 // not found
                 case 404:
                 return redirect()->route('notfound');
                 break;

                 // internal error
                 case '500':
                 return redirect()->route('notfound');
                 break;

                 default:
                     return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                 break;
             }
         }
         else
         {
                 return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```

**My routes**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

    Route::get('pagina-nao-disponivel', ['as' => 'notfound', 'uses' => 'HomeController@notfound']);
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index')->name('order');
    Route::post('/orders/create', 'OrderController@create')->name('order::create');
    Route::get('/orders/delete/{id}', 'OrderController@destroy')->name('order::delete');
    Route::get('/orders/approve/{id}', 'OrderController@confirm');
    Route::post('/orders/approve/{id}', 'OrderController@aprove');
    Route::get('/orders/edit/{id}', 'OrderController@edit')->name('order::edit');
    Route::post('/orders/update/{id}', 'OrderController@update')->name('order::update');

    /* Mail Routes */
```

**My login controller**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thank's in advance.

Comment: You don't need a slash in front of every route `Route::get('---/---home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');` Did you tried after removing it? This should work `Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');`

Comment: I fix this, but I'm still in the same problem.

Comment: is it always redirecting to your custom 404 page or laravel's default 404 page? I mean, the control is going here `case 404: return redirect()->route('notfound'); break;`

Comment: It's a custom 404 page! @JTheDev

Comment: can you please attach the result of the command `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
**in this you can remove /**
or
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = 'home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

}

**in this you can add '/home' before your home**